# Keeping track of the lowest score, in a Hi-Lo guessing game

Tags: java, swing

I am making a simple Java high-low game for school where the user must guess a number between 1 and 100. For this i am using Java Swing as my GUI.
I am counting up the guesses, which is reset when the user guesses the number and presses a restart button.

However - i would like to keep track of the best number of guesses. So i would have a "Current guesses"counter and a "Best"counter. The "best"counter should only increment the first round, and thereafter change accordingly to the lowest number of guesses.

I thought of having a currentScore and a previousScore, but i am not sure how to implement this. Any ideas?

If you need code/pictures of my interface, i can provide that. Othervise the gameclass is down below.

```
public class HiLoGame {

    private int randomNum;
    private int guessCount;
    private String result;
    private Random generator = new Random();

    public HiLoGame() {
        randomNum = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    }

    public void randomNumber() {
        randomNum = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    }

    public int getRandomNum() {
        return randomNum;
    }

    public void checkGuess(int guess) {
        if (guess < randomNum) {
            result = Integer.toString(guess) + " - Too low, try again";
            guessCount++;
        } else if (guess > randomNum) {
            result = Integer.toString(guess) + " - Too high, try again";
            guessCount++;
        } else if (guess == randomNum) {
            guessCount++;
            result = Integer.toString(guess) + " - You guessed it!";
        }
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public int getGuessCount() {
        return guessCount;
    }

    public void resetGame() {
        guessCount = 0;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with only one class variable, bestGuess initialized to integer MaxVal.

In your checkGuess, on success, update your bestGuess to guessCount if guessCount is smaller than bestGuess.

Add a method getBestGuess which returns bestGuess.

You could also handle the case where getBestGuess is called before any successful guess, so that you don't return maxint. For example, have a flag set once at least bestGuess is updated, and if calling getBestGuess before that, you could throw indicating no guess has been done yet.

Comment: @MadsJustesen If it was useful, you can indicate that on the answer :)

Comment: I would but my rep is still too low, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You state:

> I thought of having a currentScore and a previousScore, but i am not sure how to implement this. Any ideas?

Yes, create two int variables, currentScore and previousScore, and fill them with the result.

My answer seems trivial, but to be fair, so does the question. If you need more specific help, you might want to tell us more about just how you're stuck.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I had trouble storing the previous score, as my guessCount is reset every round. I might be overlooking something, it's getting late!